# Understanding the result from Encog neural network example

Tags: encog

I'm playing around with encog 3.2 for java. From the example (http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Hello_World), I make my own network with 4 neutrons in input layers and 2 neutrons in output layer.

```
1.0,1.0, actual=0.22018401281844316,ideal=1.0
-1.0,-1.0, actual=0.9903002141301814,ideal=0.0
```

Can someone explain to me how can I understand the result(actual vs ideal and those numbers before them..)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that at this stage, the network has been trained, and you are now in the testing stage.

The network has 2 inputs neurons and 1 output neuron.

The first two numbers in your result are given to the trained network as the inputs. Using the internal weights and biases (which are not changed during testing) it computes the result / output ... listed as `actual`.
`ideal` is what the result *should* be, ie the number listed in the dataset for that sample/row.

Generally when you want a 0 or 1 output (eg one of n) you will round the `actual` result.
So in this case the network computes

`1 XOR 1 = 0.22, (rounded = 0)` which is wrong (according to ideal).
`-1 XOR -1 = 0.99, (rounded = 1)` which is also wrong